# Remove short link tag from particular page

Tags: tags, shortlink

I want to remove the short link header tag from a specific page. Please suggest me a filter guys. I want to remove the entire

```
<link rel='shortlink'...
```

section from a specific page. Adding a filter to the wp_shortlink_wp_head will work fine? I am not sure whether i can add filter to the function just like that...

Thank you

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question. Sounds theme specific though.

Answer (score 3):

Replace 2 for ID of your page. Insert into your functions.php

```
if ( is_page(2) ){
   remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_shortlink_wp_head', 10, 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Talk about resurrecting an old question....

I had to do this recently with WordPress 4.5.3 and it didn't work at all. To make it work, I needed to wrap up the if statement in a function called by wp_head - like so:

```
function remove_shortlink() {
    if( is_page(2) ) {
        remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_shortlink_wp_head', 10, 0 );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_shortlink', 1 );
```

Replace '2' with the ID of your page. Add this to your theme's functions.php or in a plugin